Can predictors be correlated with each other in regression?
Here is my set up (longitudinal mixed effects):

Time periods: $t = 1,...,T$
Clusters: $j = 1,...,J$
Variables: $z_{jt}$, $x_{jt}$, $y_{jt}$

Initially, I wanted to make the following model (current value of Z depends on previous values of X and Y):
$$z_{jt} = \beta_1x_{j,t-1} + \beta_2y_{j,t-1} + \epsilon_{jt}$$
However in my case, the following problems exist:

X can potentially influence Y (e.g. past and current values of X can influence future values of Y)
Y can potentially influence X (e.g. past and current values of Y can influence future values of X)
Z can potentially influence both X and Y (e.g. past and current values of Z can influence future values of X and Y)

Thus, it seems like I have both endogeneity and simultaneity issues in the data.
What kind of mixed effects/longitudinal modelling strategies can I use in this situation?
Is this where SEM (Structural Equation Models) can be used? Or is a VAR model better? Instrument variable approach? 2 stage regression? Simultaneous equations?
I am not sure where to begin.

Something tells me that this would be ideally handled by a random intercept cross-lagged panel model (RI-CLPM) or STARTS model given the concern for both longitudinal and reverse causality concerns. Is my understanding correct that all three of your variables share multiple time periods?

hi Shawn. all 3 Variables are collected at the same time points. e.g. every week we measure xj, yj, zj at the same time

what do you think of the methods I listed? are any of them suitable?

RI-CLPMs and STARTS are just different versions of SEM which include random intercepts (these are essentially multi-level models but allowed to regression on each other). I don't know anything about VAR so can't comment there. Instrumental variable approaches have become somewhat controversial over the years (same for 2SLS for similar reasons, which you also mentioned). I'm not sure what you mean by simultaneous equations but SEMs by definition estimate equations simultaneously.
